# Attempting to create an RAID array in Ubuntu server 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm

I'm attempting to create a `RAID 0` RAID array on Ubuntu server 21.10, but I keep getting the following error:
`mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device`
Here is the syntax I used:

```
~$ sudo mdadm –create –verbose /dev/md0 –level=0 –raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: An option must be given to set the mode before a second device
(–verbose) is listed
```

I've seen some websites that list the syntax as:

```
sudo mdadm -–create -–verbose /dev/md0 -–level=0 -–raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

To which I get:

```
mdadm: invalid option -- '?'
Usage: mdadm --help
for help
```

I've tried removing the partitions and attempting the command without partitions, still no joy.  I've tried the `-c` vs the `--create` option, still no fun.

Do I need to install any additional packages in order to create an array?

Comment: Your commands contain some fancy utf8 characters. Some websites that focus on prettyness instead of usefulness replace `-` and `--` with fancy utf8 characters that look prettier but will not work in a command line. If you copied and pasted those lines from a website, just type them again.

Comment: You use "en dashes" instead of hyphens (minus signs) which are needed here.

Answer (score 0):

> I've seen some websites that list the syntax

The first place to look to find the behaviour/syntax of a command is the man pages on your local machine. That way you will be reading the documentation for the binary installed on your machine.

I don't know what version is installed on your machine, but on the one in front of me and others I have used 'create' is  directive and not an option; it shouldn't be prefixed with a '-'/